# How can I split a string in groups of two characters?

Tags: ruby, string

Is there a way I can use the map method to pull "bytes" out of a string?

For example, here is my original array:

```
array = ["7e01133200000bb8f67e"]
```

I would like to use the map method to get the following array:

```
mapped_array = ["7e", "01", "13", "32", "00", "00", "0b", "b8", "f6", "7e" ]
```

Is this possible?

What I'm doing now is this:

```
num = 0
new_array = []
(array[0][2..-3].length/2).times do
    new_array << array[0][2..-3][num,2]
    num += 2
end
```

It works but I would like to use a Ruby enumerator if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You could use `scan` ...

`arr.first.scan(/../)`

```
1.9.3p448 :114 > arr.first.scan(/../)
 => ["7e", "01", "13", "32", "00", "00", "0b", "b8", "f6", "7e"]
```

Comment: `/..?/` if the array can contain an uneven amount of characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
array = ["7e01133200000bb8f67e"]
array.first.chars.each_slice(2).to_a.map(&:join)
#=> ["7e", "01", "13", "32", "00", "00", "0b", "b8", "f6", "7e"]
```

Comment: `.to_a` is not needed, but I like this solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
new, old = [], ["7e01133200000bb8f67e"]
new << old.first.slice!(0,2) until old.first.empty?
p new #=> ["7e", "01", "13", "32", "00", "00", "0b", "b8", "f6", "7e"]
```